# NodeJS restify API caching best practice

Tags: javascript, node.js, caching

I am very new to NodeJS and I am building my first API using restify.
I want to find out what is best practice for caching the response data - each API call must have its own cache time.

I have looked at res.cache() but that seems to be only per user request and not a global application cache.

I then looked at [restify-cache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/restify-cache) but the documentation did not clearly tell me how to use it.

My application works like this:

server.js code:

```
var restify = require('restify');
var mysqlDB = require('./config/connection');

// REST server declaration and configuration
var server = restify.createServer({
  name: 'test-api',
  version: '0.0.1'
});

server.pre(restify.pre.sanitizePath());
server.use(restify.queryParser());
server.use(restify.acceptParser(server.acceptable));
server.use(restify.queryParser());
server.use(restify.bodyParser());

server.listen(9007, function() {
  console.log('%s listening at %', server.name, server.url);
  mysqlDB.handleDisconnect();
  console.log(new Date() +': Started Cricket API on port 9007');
});

var routes = require('./routes')(server);
```

routes.js code:

```
module.exports = function(app) {
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    return res.send("You have reached the test API");
});

var fixtures = require('./controllers/fixtures');
    app.get('/getfixtures', fixtures.getFixtures);  // Get All Fixtures
};
```

fixtures.js code snippet:

```
this.getFixtures = function (req, res, next) {

res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); 
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");

console.log("Get All Fixtures");
var mysql = mysqlDB.getConnection();

var query = "SELECT * FROM fixtures WHERE fixture_date >= CURDATE() ORDER BY fixture_date, fixture_time";          
      mysql.query(query,function(err,rows){
        if(err) {
            var status = mysqlDB.getErrorStatus(err.code);
            return res.status(status.code).send("Error : "+ status.Message);                  
        } else {
          var data = [];
          for (i in rows){
            var item = rows[i];

            var output = util.formatDate(item.fixture_date);
            item.fixture_date = output;

            data.push(item);
          };

          return res.send(data);
        }
      });
  };
```

Can someone please send me in the right direction? I don't know where to add the caching part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [node-cache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cache)
It was easy to use since I come from a Java/Play Framework background - hopefully it helps someone else in future.

Example usage:

```
var nodeCache = require( "node-cache" );
var myCache = new nodeCache();

var cachedValue = myCache.get("alltests", true);

if (cachedValue != undefined) {
  return res.send(cachedValue);
} else {
  // Do work here and then:
  success = myCache.set("alltests", valueHere, cacheTime);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From the library file:
`server.use(cache.before);` is a middleware that will be triggered to load before the request is handled, going to Redis and checking if the `header_{url}` key and `payload_{url}` exits, and at that case the value is returned.

You could put it as mentioned in this gist:
https://gist.github.com/jeffstieler/3d84fa5468c7eadb7685

```
var server = restify.createServer({
  name: 'test-api',
  version: '0.0.1'
});

server.pre(restify.pre.sanitizePath());
server.use(cache.before);
server.use(restify.queryParser());
server.use(restify.acceptParser(server.acceptable));
server.use(restify.queryParser());
server.use(restify.bodyParser());
server.on('after', cache.after);
```

In your code I would add the `cache.before` after you sanitize the path as this will be saved in Redis. also a `next()` should be included in every route cached.